# How to restore the data from DDMS & Ftp Server?

Tags: android, ftp, backup, restore

I've Backup `Contacts, Settings, Browser bookmarks & Media files` successfully using this [code](http://pastebin.com/d8P8f1Z6). These data are stored in DDMS & FTP as files. How can i restore these backedup files by programmatically. Anyone knows mean tell me the way? This is my [cursorToCSV](http://pastebin.com/FyY2hJDp) method for taking backup. Lot of thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Find the code for cursorToCSV and there should be a corresponding reverse method.
Use that to restore the backup files.

Comment: See my updated question. I've attached my CursorToCSV code. If you understand means, please give some solution for that.

Comment: You there? I've a method to restore.